# Why does the scope value not get set when testing?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I have created a unit test for my directive with angular 1.4.4:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('uiList', [
        function() {
            return {
                scope: {
                    lengthModel: '=uiList'
                },
                link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {


                    scope.$watch('lengthModel', function(newVal) {
                        scope.test=2;
                        console.log('kut');

                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

this is my test:

```
describe('Testing $emit in directive', function() {
    var scope;
    var element;
    var elementScope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.row = 1;
        element = angular.element('<ul id="rows" ui-list="row">');
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        elementScope = element.scope();
    }));

    it('should change value', function() {

        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.row = 1;
        });

        expect(elementScope.test).toEqual(2);


    });

});
```

When I run the test in webstorm I get this error:

```
Chrome 48.0.2564 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) Testing $emit in directive should emit FAILED              
        Expected undefined to equal 2.
```

I reaches the watch part of the directive because when I run karma I can see the log(=kut). How can I get a passing test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your directive to use an isolated scope so I think you should `isolateScope()` instead of `scope()` to get the isolated scope created by your directive on some element

```
elementScope = element.isolateScope();
```

Also you're trying to assign/update `row` property on the newly created scope while you're supposed to assign/update that `row` property on the parent scope of the controller enclosing your directive as you specified 2-way binding for your `lengthModel` using `lengthModel: '=uiList'`.

As shown in this [example](http://www.sitepoint.com/angular-testing-tips-testing-directives/#testing-directives-scope), I suggest you get a reference to the isolated scope, update some properties on that and see if they're reflected in the original scope object that you cached earlier.

```
it('sample test case', function(){    

    var isolatedScope = element.isolateScope();
    isolatedScope.lengthModel = 10;

    expect(scope.test).toBe(1);
});
```